# Getting list of events from page with Facebook API (Javascript SDK)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

It seems I am unable to retrive the events from a Facebook page. I have done this with photo albums (from the same page) and it works excellent. After I load the API and everything I use this function to get the events and display them:

```
function getAlbums() {
        FB.api('/___PAGE___/events', function (resp) {
            if (resp.data !== undefined) {
                for (var i = 0, l = resp.data.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var event = resp.data[i];
                    // process events here...
                }
            }
            else 
            // no events handle             
        });
    }
```

It goes straight to the handle for 0 events, meaning this is true: resp.data == undefined. So I am not getting any data from the Facebook. Couldn't find any solutions to it as other mostly came accross PHP and FQL, which I cannot use here. I eed to be able to display events no matter if the user is logged in or not.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the page you are trying to retrieve events from? Are there any age or geographic restrictions on this page? Can you get a list of events using the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

Comment: Well for this page "AdHocMedieval" the only restriction is [Age 13+]. I haven't tried it out on the Graph API Explorer yet.

Comment: You aren't getting any events because there aren't any future events for this page. For some reason, past events that ended more than 2 weeks ago aren't accessible via the API or FQL. They remain visible via Facebook though.

Answer (score 2):

As @cpilko has mentioned, there is this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165109696955100?browse=search_5092119b84f167f16476254) due to which your past events are not retrieved via the Graph API. Only the future events are retrieved. You can too subscribe to the same, bug, so as to keep yourself informed if it is fixed.